# Postgres: is work_mem part of shared_buffers

Tags: postgresql

I understand that work_mem is not shared and is reserved for each session. Can anyone please answer the below questions:

- Is work_mem allocated, part of shared_buffers value only or all the RAM available in OS(effective_cache_size) or cache excluding shared_buffers?
- Is my understanding right when I say the work_mem value is allocated/reserved to each opened session even if no queries are running in it?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

`work_mem` is allocated in the private memory of the base backend process that needs it. Essentially a simple `malloc`. I could find it in the source code, but it's a long way from using `work_mem` to actually allocating and freeing memory.

> Is work_mem allocated, part of shared_buffers value only or all the
> RAM available in OS(effective_cache_size) or cache excluding
> shared_buffers?

It is allocated as process private memory of the backend process using the free memory available to the OS. Like other malloc's.

Not related to [effective_cache_size](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html) - it's just hint for optimizer of how many memory you have for caches: both shared_buffers and OS page cache. Quote from documentation:

> When setting this parameter you should consider both PostgreSQL's shared buffers and the portion of the kernel's disk cache that will be used for PostgreSQL data files, though some data might exist in both places
> This parameter has no effect on the size of shared memory allocated by PostgreSQL, nor does it reserve kernel disk cache; it is used only for estimation purposes.

---

> Is my understanding right when I say the work_mem value is allocated/reserved to each opened session even if no queries are running in it?

Incorrect.

`work_mem` is allocated dynamically for a query operations (such as a sort or hash table). Be aware: for query operations, not for the entire query or the session. This is a common misunderstanding. Single complex query may use `work_mem` several times, one time for each operation that needs temporary memory. The memory requested during the execution of the query for work_mem will be returned to the OS after the query is completed.

Quoting from [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html):

> work_mem
>
> Sets the base maximum amount of memory to be used by a query operation (such as a sort or hash table) before writing to temporary disk files. If this value is specified without units, it is taken as kilobytes. The default value is four megabytes (4MB). Note that for a complex query, several sort or hash operations might be running in parallel; each operation will generally be allowed to use as much memory as this value specifies before it starts to write data into temporary files. Also, several running sessions could be doing such operations concurrently. Therefore, the total memory used could be many times the value of work_mem; it is necessary to keep this fact in mind when choosing the value. Sort operations are used for ORDER BY, DISTINCT, and merge joins. Hash tables are used in hash joins, hash-based aggregation, result cache nodes and hash-based processing of IN subqueries.
>
> Hash-based operations are generally more sensitive to memory availability than equivalent sort-based operations. The memory available for hash tables is computed by multiplying work_mem by hash_mem_multiplier. This makes it possible for hash-based operations to use an amount of memory that exceeds the usual work_mem base amount.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. However, can you please confirm below : 

1)If work_mem is allocated dynamically for a query operation, is it allocated completely or less than equal to the work_mem value? i.e., if work_mem is 4 MB then the query will allocate 4MB or say just 2MB if we assume 2MB is enough for the example.

2)Once the query completes in the still open session, is the memory freed or is held until the session ends?

Comment: 1. typically (can't promise about the entire postgresql codebase) memory for work_mem is allocated in a small initial chunk (like 8kb), then increased if necessary up to the work_mem limit. For example, `tuplestore` (Materialize nodes, hashjoin batch) infra works this way. 2. freed at the end of query execution, regardless of how long the session will be open

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Melkij for your clarification, I had a complete misconception about work_mem for a long time.

If the memory is freed at the end of query execution and is only used in chunks up to the work_mem limit, why is it that we get an "out of memory" error when work_mem is set to a higher value? And why do many experts suggest setting higher work_mem at session-level for complex queries and lesser value globally? Because even if you set a large value globally, it will still take less work_mem for smaller queries right1